# Configuration for VSCode, using TypeScript and jQuery

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I haven't been on VSCode for a while and it seems that now a lot is different and confuses me.

What has changed and what can I do to come back to the previous situation?

Since the time where all was fine, I had hardware issues, I had to reinstall some software, I did reinstall VSCode but still, I have issue, maybe that could be linked.

My main project is a single HTML page with TypeScript, jQuery, JSViews for which code is in GitHub and a pipeline deploys to Azure.

I used to develop with Visual Studio for several years and was confused when starting with VSCode. I had managed to make it work with Node and Lite Server, pressing F5, it was starting Chrome and I was able to debug in both VSCode and Chrome.

When starting the project, I was typing: "npm start", that was starting the web server. I was going in Terminal ->  Run Build task and there was a menu to watch.

Using "watch", my projects were recompiled each time one file was saved, I took the habit of using the "File -> Save All Files" menu when ready so compilation happens only at that time and browsers were refreshed.

I also had IntelliSense for TypeScript and jQuery when typing code and I was able to right-click an object and have the menu to find all references.

Now, I created a new project to demonstrate my issues, I can run npm start to start the web server, but to watch, I must type: tsc --watch and this recompiles the files for each changes, that is too much.
I know tasks are configured in the tasks.json file, I had this:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "option": "watch",
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc-watch"
        ]
    }
]
```

but now, those strings above are underlined as "not understood": typescript, tsconfig, option and $tsc-watch. The error description for "typescript" is: Value is not accepted. Valid values: "process"

I wanted to add jQuery in my test project with those commands :

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
npm install --save jquery
```

I saw some message about "dev-dependencies" that were new to me, is that a recent addition ? Does that mean that dev-dependencies won't be included in deployment ? That confuses me as I do need that some jQuery files be included while I agree that most of what is in node_modules doesn't have to be deployed.

I no longer have the "find all references" menu when I right-click an object and have no IntelliSense for TypeScript or jQuery. I also lose the "File -> Save All Files" menu, is that an option or from a new version of VSCode ?

Here are extracts of my files:

```
/// launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
             "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:1234/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"   /*don't know where that workspace folder is setup...*/
        }
    ]
}

/// node_modules > jquery > package.json
{
  "name": "jquery",
  "version": "3.6.1",
  "main": "dist/jquery.js",
  "homepage": "https://jquery.com",
}

/// package.json
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./js/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lite": "lite-server --port 1971",
    "start": "npm run lite"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}

/// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["ES2017", "DOM"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "js",
        "rootDir": "ts",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true    
    },
    "include": ["ts/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["docs/*"]
}
```

I understand there is a difference in jQuery versions but I don't understand how it should be.

How can I fix all those little things?

Comment: This looks like an issue with VSCode configuration and not about using jQuery or @types/jquery as your project dependencies.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to remove that tag, hoping I'll find some help on that !!  Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, Typescript features were disabled in VSCode.
In VSCode extensions, I searched for @builtin typescript and javascript and enable TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features !!